# How to use regex in notepad ++ to search for emails with specific domains

Tags: regex

I am trying to use Notepad ++ to delete emails that end in @domain2.serverdata.net

here is a string example:

> smtp:name@domain1.com;SMTP:name@domain2.com;smtp:name@domain2.serverdata.net;smtp:name@domain3.com;smtp:name_e4d1fe3d-e985-40d0-bc65-32c57c9b14d1@domain2.serverdata.net

I was hoping to use:

> ;smtp:.*@domain2.serverdata.net

but it captures `SMTP:name@domain2.com` as well

Answer (score 1):

Try Regex: `;?smtp:[\w.-]+?@domain2\.serverdata\.net`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GYcoeG/3)

Comment: This one works on regex101.com but it gives an error "Find: Invalid regular expression" for me when i test in Notepad++ v7.5.4 (32-bit), the question says the context is Notepad++

Comment: add a `*` after that leading ';' and this is the best answer

Comment: Thanks @Gus, I've added a `?` instead of `*`

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\A|;)smtp:[^@]*@domain2\.serverdata\.net`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:\A|;)                    # non capture group, beginning of file or semicolon, 
                              this allows to delete the first email of the file 
                              that haven't a semicolon before it
smtp:                       # literally
[^@]+                       # 1 or more any character that is not @
@domain2\.serverdata\.net   # literally
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
smtp:[^@]+@domain2\.serverdata\.net(;)?
```

Comment: Note that this will not match an email address at the start.

Comment: But now you might possibly get `;;` in the result.

Comment: How is that? Can you give an example?

Comment: See the replacement value https://regex101.com/r/vbjWnK/1 but perhaps that is ok with the OP.

Comment: Nicely spotted, gave it another go, it still has a shortcoming of leaving a semicolon behind in case a @domain2.serverdata.net email appears last in the list but maybe it good enough for him

Answer (score 0):

Regexes will usually capture as much as possible. For instance: `START.*STOP` applied to the following text:

```
STARTsghlegdSTOPfsgikbSTARTsvdinusSTOPwegtgw
```

will capture this part:

```
STARTsghlegdSTOPfsgikbSTARTsvdinusSTOPwegtgw
^------------------------------------^
```

In your case, the `.*` captures everything up to the last instance of `@domain2.serverdata.net`. You don't want to use `.` (any character), you want to use "any character except '@'" which is written like this: `[^@]`.
So your full regex would be `smtp:[^@]*@domain2\.serverdata\.net`. I also dropped the initial `;` since it would prevent you from capturing the first mail address.

Comment: If you drop the initial `;` you could possibly end up with `;;` in the result.

Comment: true, I guess starting with ;? would be ideal